# How can I use Androiddrier using appium in serenity-bdd framework?

Tags: android, appium, cucumber-jvm, thucydides, serenity-bdd

I am using serenity-bdd with cucumber-jvm for my test framework. I want to run my tests on android emulator using Appium.

Serenity-bdd by default instantiate webdriver which opens firefox. How can I execute my webdriver tests on android emulator?

Answer (score 0):

```
driver = new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```